# Что значит "Че ты паришься"?

Tags: сленг, phrase

Привет всем,

What does "Че ты паришься" mean? The only information I found on it was from http://www.lexiophiles.com/english/10-words-everybody-needs-to-know-before-going-to-russia-part-2 which says it literally means "why are you taking the steam bath". But it also mentions that there is a figurative meaning of the phrase.

I'm wondering what the figurative meaning is, in other words, when a native speaker says this phrase, what is he intending to say?

Спасибо!

Comment: Here's (sort of) cover for "Don't worry, be happy" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yWHRJEjxtCc

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It means something like "Why are you worried?" or even "Why are you giving a sh*t?" due to informality of the phrase.
Figurative meaning of "париться" comes from sweating while steam bathing like after hard job and means "to worry",  "to care" or "to have trouble".
Also you can use it like

- Не парься. (Don`t worry.)
- Я запарился. (I'm tired, I'm worn out or something like that.)
- У меня запара. (I've got troubles.)

Answer (score 2):

It's a slang sentence for **"Don't worry! It isn't worth it."** It reminds me of the song "Don't worry, be happy!" There's a more neutral synonym of that **"Не заморачивайся"** or "Не морочь (себе) голову".